# What is the purpose of parentheses in "var items = [Int]()"?

Tags: swift, syntax, parentheses

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn its syntax. I saw this code online.

```
var items = [Int]()
```

I know

- var = declaring a variable
- items = the name of the variable is 'items'
- [Int] = array of Int

However, I'm not sure the purpose of the () after [Int]. I know the code wouldn't compile without the (), but what is its purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is initializing a new instance of an Array that will contain Ints. It is a shorthand of this syntax:

```
var items = Array<Int>()
```

Instead of `Array<Int>` for the type you can use `[Int]` instead.

A third variation would be to explicitly state the type, and then assign an empty array.

```
var items: [Int] = []
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out!! Just to clarify, does the () represents a constructor for the array? Or it represent something else?

Comment: @dzjustinli exactly correct.  It's invoking the constructor with no arguments.

Comment: Yes, as David says, it is constructing a new object. One thing to keep in mind is Swift doesn't really call them constructors, instead they are called  initializers. I know it is knitpicky, but it may help you if you have to look for information on other parts of initialization.

Comment: David Berry, Mr Beardsley, thank you very much for helping out! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Any time. Good luck with your project!